# How to hide a field of a content type except when editing?

Tags: nodes, users, entities

I'm using Drupal 7 and have a custom content type that I've given authenticated users the ability to add and edit. Instead of giving them the ability to delete nodes, I've added a Boolean checkbox titled "Delete?" to the content type that they can check when editing the node. This prevents them from deleting a node without any administrative review. Is there anyway to hide this checkbox when they're adding a new node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement `hook_form_alter()` and check whether `$form['nid']['#value']` is empty, if empty then it is creation else it is update. If creation then hide the  field by setting `#access` property to `FALSE`.

**UPDATE** : Create a custom module and use the following code with needed modification.

Here is an example to hide `tags` field  in `article` content type.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id=='article_node_form' && empty($form['nid']['#value'])){
     $form['field_tags']['#access']=FALSE;
  }
}
```

[Here](http://webemania.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-module-in-drupal-in-three-easy-steps) is a tutorial on how to create a custom module.

Comment: So I'm fairly new to Drupal, where/how exactly would I implement hook_form_alter()? Or can you point me in the direction of a resource that explains how? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @gussbus updated the answer